# I am getting error "No quota is available to deploy this model version and deployment type." for GPT-4

Tags: azure-openai, gpt-4

I am trying to deploy GPT-4 but getting the screenshot error. I have added "Cognitive Services OpenAI Contributor" role assignment to my "user" under Azure Open AI -> Access control (IAM). Do you need to do anything else? Why am I getting this error? Do you have any idea?

[image: Error Message]

[image: Permission Window]

I was expecting to deploy GPT4 model succesufully.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and I could solve it by choosing another region.

Previously I used Germany and Europe, but it seems like GPT-4 is not available there, yet. After creating a new ressource and choosing US, I could successfully deploy GPT-4.